# Copper as an adjective to refer to something made of copper

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, attributive-nouns

According to the dictionaries, "copper" aside from that is the name of a **reddish-brown soft metal**, as an adjective means a **reddish brown color** too. I need to make sure if it can be used as an adjective to refer to something like a dish, etc. which is **made of copper** or I have to use **copper made**?

Comment: And do you have any research to present to us?

Comment: @Lambie having a look on all dictionaries' definitions is what I did. The only reference to copper as an adjective alluding to something made of copper is **a coin or token made of copper or bronze** which doesn't satisfy my need.

Comment: just try googling then: copper coins, copper plates, copper pipes

Comment: The term you're looking for is "[noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)".

Comment: We assume whatever research you did didn’t help you, because if it did, you wouldn’t be asking your question. You still should include it in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can certainly say "copper dish", "copper penny", etc.

The names of some materials need to change form when used as an adjective (like "wool**en** blanket", "wood**en** spoon", oak**en** bucket ...).

Silk can go either way: "silk**en** fabric" or "silk purse". But copper just stays "copper".

[I thought I had seen the word "coppern" used in old-fashioned type writing, but looking it up, I can't find any sign of its existence.]

Comment: silver, gold, copper, steel etc. don't change either

Comment: @Lambie golden?

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki "Golden" often refers to the color rather than the material. For example, *the man with golden hair sells gold jewelry*.

Comment: @Tashus makes sense, as "The Man with the Golden Gun" very probably does not have a gun entirely made of gold. It probably would fail at the second use - and be prohibitively heavy...

Answer (score 9):

Yes, "copper" can be used as an attributive noun.  These examples describe various items made out of the metal:

> Copper roofs turn green over time.
>
> In America, most new houses have copper wiring.
>
> We ate off of copper plates.

Comment: This, by the way, is why the dictionaries failed to give "made of copper" as a meaning for the adjective form. As Jasper says, it's an attributive noun when used in this sense, not an adjective.